# Regression Tree when target is a ratio

Tags: regression, cart, scikit-learn

I am learning a regression tree for data of the form $(x_i,y_i)$:
$x_i = (1, 0, 1, ...., 1 , 1)$ a multiple input vector and $y$ is a ratio of the number of observations divided by the number of trials for that input. so $y_i = (obs/trials)$. 
My problem is that most of the data is sparse, meaning that most of the inputs will have 0 observations and some trials and then its corresponding $y_i$ will be zero (let's say no input has trials =0). My problem is that when I learn a tree, in each leaf the tree calculates the average of $y_i$ and that is not what I need since all the $y_i=0$ are being discarded in the average. What I would like to do is to sum up, the number of trials in each leaf, and the number of observations and make the division for each leaf instead of averaging the ratios (or even each one by itself (observation, trials)).
I am using sci-kit for the tree model. 
Is there any intelligent way to do what i want without implementing it from scratch. I mean suing tree libraries as sci-kit?

Comment: Is the total number of trials huge? If not, you could try to replace each data line by n ='trial' lines and a 0/1 response variable.

Comment: No, it is not huge.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the answer provider as comment by Michael Mayer.

Another option which should work is to use only $obs$ value as a dependent variable and $trials$ as a weight for observation. I do not know scikit learn, and, because I do not know python either, I was not able to understand if they weights the values when averaging at the leave nodes. As far as I was able to understand, however, it seems that Weka implementation does that.

Finally I suggest to ask yourself why did you try to work with ratios anyway. Usually working with ratios is not straightforward. But the main problem I see is that ratios loose a lot of information for what I think you want to know.

There are zeros which gives you trouble. I think however a bigger problem is the ratio itself. What I mean is $1/2$ is not at all the same with $50/100$. The ratio is the same, however, if you think about how confidence you have in each observation is not. $50$ observations from $100$ trials is much more evidence than $1$ observation from $2$ trials, even if the expected value is the same. Using ratio you loose one dimension of your data for nothing but getting meaningless results.

Comment: The point is that I am interested to learn the probability for certain event to occur. For my training examples ${x_i,y_i)}$ ($x_i$ being a vector and $y_i$ a scalar) the probability that a given vector $x$ will produce an output $y$ or not. the number of times the output ($y$) is one is the number of observations for a given number of trials (say $n$). So I am interested in the probability that for a certain vector $x$, what is the ration $ \sum(y)/n$, meaning, what is the probability that, that vector would produce an output of $y=1$ for a future vector $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you seem to be trying to do is predicting the probability of some event occurring. This is usually modeled using a Bernouilli distribution.

There are two (unequal) ways of doing this with Gradient Boosting :

- either (statistically dubious) use the "ratios" successes/trials as your target $y$ and use the number of trials $n$ as a weight vector, and use gradient boosting with a gaussian distribution. This will generate an unbiased estimation of your probability, but has the (huge) disadvantage of not being bound to $[0,1]$, and can give some odd results.
- the correct way to do this is use gradient boosting with a Bernouilli loss. To do this in R for example, you will have to disagregate your data, so that your response is either a 0 or a 1 depending on success/failure, and then use gbm with a "bernouilli" parameter (similarly in scikit learn, use the binomial loss). I'm not aware of a way to do this with successes and trials aggregated on each line, so if your data containts a very large amount of trials and disagregation would result in too large a dataset, you might have to customize the model yourself.